# BizTalk Oracle WCF Adapter OS Authentication

Tags: oracle, wcf, authentication, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm trying to get OS authentication setup for a WCF-Custom Oracle send port in BizTalk 2013 R2.  I can connect to the Oracle db using OS Auth in SQL Developer (When logged in as my BizTalk service account) and Visual Studio can use OS auth as well so I know that the account is active and has the correct permissions in the Oracle Db.  Unfortunately, the BizTalk adapter throws the following exception when I try to query the database:

```
The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "MySendPort" with URL "oracledb://MyTnsName". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.ConnectionException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Adapters.OracleCommon.OracleCommonConnectionWrapper..ctor(String connectionString, OracleCommonExecutionHelper executionHelper)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.OracleDB.OracleDBConnection.Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.IConnection.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Adapters.OracleDB.OracleDBConnection.Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.IConnection.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Design.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Guid clientId, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Design.ConnectionPool.GetConnectionHandler[TConnectionHandler](Guid clientId, TimeSpan timeout, MetadataLookup metadataLookup, String& connectionId)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Channels.AdapterRequestChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.GetChannel[TChannel](IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage, ChannelFactory`1& cachedFactory)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage)".
```

If I change the user name from "/" to a local Oracle account and password, BizTalk can query the db just fine.

I have both the 32bit and 64bit oracle 12c clients installed with ODAC 2.121.2.0.  The Oracle env variables are first in the system PATH variable and I've added a binding redirect to the Microsoft.Adapters.OracleDB.config file in BizTalk to reference the newer ODAC version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you registered the ODAC component after the installation ?